# docker desktop kubernetes can't pull from private registry

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm running docker desktop with the built-in kubernetes cluster. I've got an image in an on-prem gitlab instance. I create a project API key and on the local machine I can do a `docker push gitlab.myserver.com/group/project:latest` and similarly pull the image after doing a `docker login gitlab.myserver.com` with the project bot username and the API key.

I create a kubernetes secret with `kubectl create secret docker-registry myserver --docker-server=gitlab.myserver.com --docker-username=project_42_bot --docker-password=API_KEY`

I then create a pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - data_generator.py
    image: gitlab.myserver.com/group/project:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: foo
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: myserver
```

but I get an access forbidden on the pull.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a secret for registry login by running the command below :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret_name> --docker-server=<your.registry.domain.name> --docker-username=<user> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<your_email>
```

And then use this secret for deployment:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: 
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: server
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <secret_name>
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) and [github](https://github.com/containerd/cri/issues/848) link for more information.